# Wordpress 3.8.1: Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I use Wordpress 3.8.1. and created a website with the free business theme "Corp". My problem: Javascript doesn't work, for example it is not possible to toggle accordions and also the sroll-to-top-button doesn't work. I had a look in the console and found the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

It refers to the jquery.js-file. The version that the theme comes with is v1.10.2.

I then had a look at the demo page of the "Corp" theme and there everything works fine. There is no error message in the console. I found out that the demo page is based on Wordpress 3.5.2.

I am not so familiar with Wordpress yet. What could the be the next useful steps to solve this javascript problem?

Comment: Where is the error coming from?

Comment: @orourkedd as mentioned the error comes from the jquery.js-file

Comment: did you install all of the demo info with the theme?

Comment: also, do you have this installed online so it can be looked at?

Comment: @orourkedd: the console says on line 5, but I cannot find any "name" string using the search function of my browser...

Comment: it's probably minified so the location of the error is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php wp_head(); ?> and <?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

put this two line.
first wp_head() is just put before completed  and second wp_footer() is put before completed

this is hook for a plugin and javascript